# Stop running function when press home key or lock key of phone in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I always update the table after 10s with setInterval(). Problem is still running background when I press home key or lock key. I wrote the clearInterval() in both ngOnDestroy() and ionViewDidExit(). But they are not working. I want to stop the setInterval() when I press hardware home key or lock key of phone. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: if you are using Cordova use Ionic Platform APi to detect you app is in background or not and if you are ising capacitor use capacitors App plugin to detect app state change.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I used platform.pause and platform.resume.